# Setting all Excel sheets at a defined zoom level

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have more than twenty sheets in an Excel workbook (file). Is there some code snippet or a command I could apply/use so that all sheets could be reset to let's say 85% zoom level?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
Sub SetZoom()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85 ' change as per your requirements
    Next ws
End Sub
```

BTW, if you simply select all worksheets in your workbook using the tabs you can then set the zoom to 85% and it will apply to all worksheets

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst Use VBA `=P`

Comment: While this solution still requires you to use `.Select`, you can update the zoom for all sheets at once without looping: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715890/2727437

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SetZoom()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'Optional
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This code is similar from the above, but it is not necessary to select all worksheets in your workbook before running the macro. Instead of using `ws.Select` and `Next ws` that not work correctly unless you select the worksheets, change to `ws.Activate` and `Next` to set the zoom for all the sheets. As optional, the `ScreenUpdating` can be disabled for a workbook with a lot of sheets.

Comment: While this code may help with the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Klaus!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub FixSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        ws.UsedRange.Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True 'Zoom sur la sélection
        ActiveCell.Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```