# Apply existing macro to entire workbook regardless of amount of worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

With little to no "information technology" background, I created a macro using the record function that changes the layout (column width and page orientation to fit on one page when printed) of a spreadsheet (excel 2010) only when the run command is given. **That was the easy part**

The issue is that it only changes the ActiveSheet which requires me to click on every sheet in the workbook and perform the macro. There can be anywhere from 1 to 15 sheets in the workbook with varying lines of data. (just depends on the day); I would like to alter the macro to run on the "ACTIVE WORK BOOK" regardless of the amount of worksheets contained within?

Here is a copy of the entire macro:

```
Sub VerificationWorkbook()
'
' VerificationWorkbook Macro
' Verification Workbook
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+V
'
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 4.14
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 3.71
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 2.29
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 5.43
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 4.71
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 5.86
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 5.57
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 6.57
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 5.14
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the ["For Each...Next" statement](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805575249990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=f15da15a%2D3ded%2D4226%2D8fff%2Dd23b40523cbc). It allows you to apply code to each sheet in your workbook.

For example,

```
Dim ws As Variant
For Each ws In Worksheets
  'apply code to ws as if it is the only
  'active worksheet
Next
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953703/setting-all-excel-sheets-at-a-defined-zoom-level/5953765#5953765) for a good example to get you started.