# VBA to set Zoom level on Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA that will set the zoom level based on the screen resolution.
But its working only for ActiveWindow when you open workbook.
How can I add this across all worksheets in Excel?

```
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Public Sub ScreenRes()
    Dim lResWidth As Long
    Dim lResHeight As Long
    Dim sRes As String

    lResWidth = GetSystemMetrics32(0)
    lResHeight = GetSystemMetrics32(1)
    sRes = lResWidth & "x" & lResHeight
    Select Case sRes
        Case Is = "800x600"
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
        Case Is = "1024x768"
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 125
        Case Else
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    End Select
End Sub
```

I will call this module on the Workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ScreenRes
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, you want it to change the zoom level for all open windows, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

building on @Jeeped answer you could place in ThisWorkbook code pane the following code:

```
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Worksheets
        .Select
        ActiveWindow.zoom = ScreenResToZoom
    End With
End Sub

Public Function ScreenResToZoom() As Long
    Select Case GetSystemMetrics32(0) & "x" & GetSystemMetrics32(1)
        Case Is = "800x600"
            ScreenResToZoom = 75
        Case Is = "1024x768"
            ScreenResToZoom = 125
        Case Else
            ScreenResToZoom = 100
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Nice (and **proper**) use of a function to return a number to be used in the zoom command rather than attempting to change the zoom level within the function itself.

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks. I agree with your comment. BTW what's the time over there?

Comment: Currently UTC-0700.

Comment: @user3598756 and  You guys made my day!!Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10):

Select all of the [Worksheet Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) using the [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508.aspx) and the [Application.ActiveWindow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835855.aspx) will point to them all.

```
With Worksheets
    .Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
End With
```

Comment: fine. And the `With`-`End With` could also be avoided: `Worksheets.Select`/`ActiveWindow.Zoom = 7`

Comment: @Jeeped, Sorry, I dint get your point. Do you want me to add the code given by you in each select case in my code?

Comment: @Manu, see my answer to help you not to wait for Jeeped awakening. But credits stay on Jeeped

Comment: to be clear - for all answers this requires worksheets to be visible.