# Excel freeze panes after scroll

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a pivot table containing many filters.
The headers I'd like to freeze are on line 25 of the sheet. 
On any screen with a resolution smaller then 1920 x 1080 none of the row below will show while scrolling.

Is there a way to freeze the pane when a user scrolls down and line 25 if the top visible row, then unfreeze the panes again when the user scrolls up above line 25?

Comment: Did you try something ? Can you post your code ? We are here to help you on programming problems and not code for you :)

Comment: @Teasel I have loads of code in the templates VBA already, sadly none of it relevant to this question. I know how to freeze the panes (recording a macro is the easiest way to find out), so I guess the coding part of the question comes down reading the scroll event. I was also expecting answers like "no, it is not possible".

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, that should be possible:

- Chip Pearson: [Detecting Scrolling In A Worksheet Window](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm)
- Stack Overflow: [How to determine if a worksheet Cell is Visible/Displayed in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943260/8112776)

However, it would probably take you **a lot less work** to instead, **reorganize** your workbook so you're not using Row 25 as a header <sub>(ever)</sub>.  It sounds like you might have "too much stuff" crammed onto one worksheet.  **:-)**

Comment: Too much stuff? You have no idea :-p
Writing reports for an online system would make most of my problems go away. Sadly Excel is an offline technology that is readily available to all our customers so we are expected to do magic that Excel was never designed for.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to ship/deploy an external DLL to the consumers of the reports I work with. It is already difficult enough to have the users upgrade to a Power Pivot enabled version of Excel. Everything (data and custom code) must be contained in one Excel file.

Comment: I've been in the same position, and it bites: hands tied while expected to work miracles.  However when you say `already difficult enough to have the users upgrade to a Power Pivot enabled version`, is this an upgrade that is already complete?  If not, how is it being rolled out?  If you have any influence on that, it's not hard to pack a DLL along with the upgrade.

Comment: **But that idea aside** if I understand your situation, as long as you are **willing** to reorganize your workbook, it will only make it easier on the users.  I never suggesting splitting anything up to multiple files, but organization always has room for improvement. ***"Adding code to makeup for a bug that occurs for certain users because of poor workbook design"*** is a **TERRIBLE** idea, and is sure to backfire and cause other issues in the future. Granted, it's easy for me to make assumptions without seeing your actual workbook, but I've seen similar situations before,...

Comment: ...including in my own work years ago.  A spreadsheet or DB grows too fast, too unruly,and it's amazing what a motivated person can work around.  Why don't you just automatically change the user's monitor resolution with VBA.  The code is shorter than capturing scrolls.  Sound absurd?  It is -- equally as adding complicated code to an already-convoluted workbook, to work what is nothing more than improper design.  (Kind of like building a new road to go _around_ a pothole,  I'm not trying to be a jerk, but sometimes it's easier to see from the outside.  :-)

Comment: If you'd like some suggestions with fresh eyes on an alternate way to solve your issue I'd have to take a look at the actual workbook; up to you.  Good luck either way!

Comment: ...now I feel bad for "bashing your baby" (I know what that's like too!) but my "resolution" comment got me thinking:  Couldn't you just programmatically **Zoom Out**  (like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39726602/8112776) *"on open"* if the screen resolution isn't going to show all the data?   ...,?  (For the record, it's still a _workaround_, not a solution, but if it works........ **:-)**

Comment: Wow. Those are a lot of thoughts.
Truth be told, the pivot is built dynamically depending on the number of fields the customer wants to see. Things like different address fields (country, city, suburb, region, etc.) and different product parameters (brand, description, schedule, ingredients, etc.) so in reality the headers could possibly be on line 38, albeit highly unlikely.

A part of the legacy problem is that all reports need to be "standard". This includes dropdowns and checkboxes and descriptions across all reports as well.

Comment: As for the influence on distributing the DLL ... no chance. These reports are distributed far and wide across the country (and some places outside the country) so chances are that I will never deal with more than a few customers. Most of these customers are also not entirely computer literate, other than being able to open an email/network file in Excel. Most of them are then also hidden behind very strict corporate security, which already makes enabling macros difficult.

Comment: Changing the resolution would also not be an option for similar reasons. Complicating that even more is that a lot of the customers use very old technology and don't have the option to use an HD monitor. A lot of managers walk around with laptops with a max resolution of 1366 x 768.
Zooming out in these cases will then make the text too small to read.

Comment: In this case I am all for the "baby bashing" you mentioned. I wish I could bash this baby so badly that I can rewrite all of it in a proper online web based reporting tool, but Excel is what people have and Excel is what we will force ourselves to use. We have already done magic with these reports, but there is only so much magic that Excel is capable of doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160506/discussion-between-dj-van-wyk-and-ashleedawg).

Comment: Of course something like a web based solution would be ideal but I was actually referring to revamping with Excel.