# Create a zoom in and out loop function in Excel mapped by CTRL+ and CTRL-

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulty correctly specifying the code. I want to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> in Excel and increase zoom by 5% each time; vice-versa for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

I've tried to map zoom functions to the `Application.onkey` function, but have not had success. This is much more straight forward when mapped to an actual letter. I'm also unsure on how to create the looping effect.

```vb
Sub Zoom()
    Application.Onkey "^{=}", "ZoomIn"
End Sub

Sub ZoomIn()
    ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 105
End Sub
```

Macro runs but does not result in desired effect; does not actually do anything.

Comment: `ActiveWindow.Zoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom + 5`

Answer (score 0):

how about: not tested just acc. MS Docs it might be a idea to use debug.print to figure out if the keystroke is fired - even nothing happens you can see that the key defs are working. And for sure you can also call zoomin by F5 to see if the zoom is working. This might simplify to track down your problem.

Somewhere in your application to be called at least once:

```
  sub keymap
    Application.OnKey "^{+}", "zoomin" 
    Application.OnKey "^{-}", "zoomout" 
    Application.OnKey "^{=}", "zoomreset"
  end sub

  Sub zoomin() 
   debug.print "in"
   current = ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage
   ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = current+5
  End Sub

  Sub zoomout()
  debug.print "out"
   current = ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage
   ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage =  current-5
  End Sub

  Sub zoomreset()
   debug.print "default"
   ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage =  100
  End Sub
```

Comment: `.Zoom` is _not_ a valid Property of `ActiveWindow.View`, so this code won't compile.  Whats needed is just `ActiveWindow.Zoom`

Comment: so we got a annswer :)

Comment: Thank you both! I'm still getting a run-time error '424' object required when running. I've deleted view from code. Thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715728/vba-to-set-zoom-level-on-sheets?rq=1

Comment: On 64bit you might have to use SavePtr  in front of the declaration

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are interested in a solution here, I've coded the following, which is working very well for me:

```
Sub KeyMap()
' Key Mapping for zooming in and out using CTRL+= and CTRL +-
Application.OnKey "^{=}", "ZoomIn"
Application.OnKey "^{-}", "ZoomOut"
End Sub

Sub ZoomIn()
Dim ZP As Integer
ZP = Int(ActiveWindow.Zoom * 1.05)
If ZP > 400 Then ZP = 400
ActiveWindow.Zoom = ZP
End Sub

Sub ZoomOut()
Dim ZP As Integer
ZP = Int(ActiveWindow.Zoom * 0.95)
If ZP < 10 Then ZP = 10
ActiveWindow.Zoom = ZP
End Sub
```