# Using Excel VBA to modify .zoom property in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, zooming

I am writing a complex VBA app that imports data from one workbook, transforming the data as it imports. As part of this import process, a calculation is made that picks up the .text value of a certain cell (and this cannot be changed to .value), however this means if the source workbook is zoomed out, this imports **########** values, as that is what is displayed.

I am trying to modify the .zoom setting in the activesheet of the source workbook to be 100% zoom. An example of the code used is below.

```
Dim SourcePath as String    
Dim SourceWorkbook as Object

FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename 'Opens dialogue for user to select source
    If FilePath <> "" Then 'Checks that the filepath is completed
       SourcePath = FilePath 'Stores the filepath for source
    End If

Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(SourcePath)

SourceWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet.Zoom = 100
```

I am getting a **run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set** error, so I am assuming the logic here is poor.

Can anybody suggest a way of making this work? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
    Sheets("Sheet Name").Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 30 ' Zoom Set to 30%
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I shall try the following logic:

    Workbooks(SourceWorkbook).Worksheets(SourceSheet).Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    Workbooks(DestinationWorkbook).Worksheets(SourceSheet).Select

Really appreciate this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no `zoom` property on worksheet, i think you need to change `zoom` property of a window!

[Setting all Excel sheets at a defined zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953703/setting-all-excel-sheets-at-a-defined-zoom-level)